# How to use a subdomain for images in opencart 2?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

This is my config file. I have changed for image subdomain but images do not load.

```
<?php

    // HTTP
    define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.Yek.com/');
    define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://img.Yek.com/');

    // HTTPS
    define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.Yek.com/');
    define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://img.Yek.com/');

    // DIR
    define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/Yek/public_html/catalog/');
    define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/');
    define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/database/');
    define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/Yek/public_html/catalog/language/');
    define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/Yek/public_html/catalog/view/theme/');
    define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/config/');
    //define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/Yek/public_html/image/');//defult For Images/catlog on main host
    define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/Yek/public_html/img/image/'); // image/catalog in download host

    define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/cache/');
    define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/download/');
    define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/logs/');
    define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/upload/');
    define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/Yek/public_html/system/modification/');


    // DB
  ....
?>
```

this is my image.php . edit for me?
not know where edit this code........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<?php
class ModelToolImage extends Model {
    public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {
        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
            return;
        }

        $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $old_image = $filename;
        $new_image = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;

        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image) || (filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image) > filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image))) {
            $path = '';

            $directories = explode('/', dirname(str_replace('../', '', $new_image)));

            foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

                if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
                    @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777);
                }
            }

            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);

            if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
                $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
                $image->resize($width, $height);
                $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
            } else {
                copy(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image, DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
            }
        }

        if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
            return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $new_image;
        } else {
            return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $new_image;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/catalog/model/tool/image.php
found $this->config->get('config_url')
and change

```
protected function getImageUrl($new_image) {
    $parts = explode('/', $new_image);
    $new_url = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', $parts));
    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
        return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $new_url;
    }
    else {
        return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $new_url;
    }
}
```

Comment: found this code but error,edit question,please edit my code

Answer (score 2):

**Point your sub-domain to your image directory**

While adding sub-domain in your hosting control panel you have to point it to your image directory. If you do not have access to control panel you have to ask your administrator.

Comment: I have access to a control panel,The main control panel as well as control panel download.I configuration settings correct?

Comment: No , when change to `define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/Yek/public_html/mage/');` show Picture of Site in the catalog of main host

Comment: You are not clear here. DIR_IMAGE remains same but only HTTP_IMAGE change to show image url to display as subdomain included url. It must work for you. But you may want different thing.

Comment: i want to show picture of site from host Download with address img.yek.com ,for this. change `define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/Yek/public_html/image/'); ` To `define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/Yek/public_html/img/image/');`and add `define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://img.Yek.com/');` but with changes , not show folders for select picuter for product. and not show picture site.

Comment: To clarify: DIR_IMAGE is the **absolute image directory path** used by php to determine where a file is within the system, PHP must have access by setting the open base directory if needed, or by setting the subdomain to point to the image directory. The problem with the latter is it can cause issues when using SEO rewrites you may find you hit a redirect loop. the HTTP(S)_IMAGE constants are used for links on a page. If possible you should serve HTTPS images no matter the security of your page. Non-ssl content will break SSL but the reverse has no ill on security.